# Jquery to update price when one or more options selected

Tags: jquery

I have an online shop and against the products you can have different variables like so:

```
Colour: <select class="vars" name="size">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option data-price="-10.00" value="B">blue</option>
    <option data-price="+20.00" value="G">green</option>
    <option data-price="+30.00" value="Y">yellow</option>
</select>
<br>
Size: <select class="vars" name="size">
    <option>Select an option</option>
    <option data-price="-1.00" value="S">Small</option>
    <option data-price="+2.00" value="M">Medium</option>
    <option data-price="+3.00" value="L">Large</option>
</select>
```

There can be between 1 and 5 of these depending on the product.

Data-price contains what need to happen to the start price of the page.

So if the start price was 10.00 and I select yellow it needs to update the price of `<span class="item-price">10.00</span>` to 40.00

but then if I also select small it wants to update it again to 39.

I have got it half working in the jsfiddle below but im stuck on two parts. Updating the price with the span on update and also when an update is made that it checks makes all the price changes.

Hope this makes sense.

http://jsfiddle.net/gjbKY/5/

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "also when an update is made that it checks makes all the price changes."

Comment: Sorry, what i mean is If i select yellow the price will become 40 and then select Large the price becomes 43 and not 13.

Comment: did you want it to behave like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gjbKY/9/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate the total price, get the value of both and add them to the base price  whenever the value is changed on one of the selects. You can display this in the `item-price` span using the `html()` function.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gjbKY/10/)**

**HTML**

```
Colour: <select class="vars" name="size">
        <!-- set defaults to price=0 to save you from having to do validation -->
        <option data-price="0">Select an option</option> 
        <option data-price="-10.00" value="B">blue -10</option>
        <option data-price="20.00" value="G">green +20</option>
        <option data-price="30.00" value="Y">yello +30</option>
</select>
<br>
Size: <select class="vars" name="size">
        <option data-price="0">Select an option</option>
        <option data-price="-1.00" value="S">Small</option>
        <option data-price="2.00" value="M">Medium</option>
        <option data-price="3.00" value="L">Large</option>
</select>
<br>
<span id="item-price">20</span> <!-- better to use an ID than class, ID's are faster to look up -->
```

**jQuery**

```
var basePrice = 20;

$(".vars").change(function() {
    newPrice = basePrice;

    $('.vars option:selected').each(function() {
        newPrice += $(this).data('price'); //get price of each selected option and add them to the newPrice
    });

    $('#item-price').html(newPrice); //display new price
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i had to add Number().  newPrice += Number($(this).data('price'));