# Add sum of dropdowns into a txt field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, calculator

How do i take a group of dropdowns and add the values on change into a text field?

```
<select name="qty[1]" id="qty[1]">
<option selected="selected">500</option>
<option>1000</option>
<option>1500</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>2500</option>
</select>

<select name="qty[2]" id="qty[2]">
<option selected="selected">500</option>
<option>1000</option>
<option>1500</option>
<option>2000</option>
<option>2500</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="total_qty" id="total_qty" />
```

So if i select 1000, the total txtbox will change to 1000, then if i select 2000 from the other selectbox the total should change to 3000

Comment: This answer may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324013/jquery-to-update-price-when-one-or-more-options-selected/17324409#17324409

Comment: Bind a `.change()` function to your `select`s, and add the value of one `option:selected` to the other and set `input` value with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var selects = $('select[name^=qty]');
selects.change(function(){
    var value = 0;
    selects.each(function(){ value += +this.value; });
    $('#total_qty').val(value);
}).trigger('change');
```

It will work for two `<select>` boxes or twenty without changing the code.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/eYmF8/2/

Comment: using this right? `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @user2405912 - yes, place that just before the `</body>` tag and straight after that put the code from my answer like this `<script> PASTE MY CODE HERE </script>`.

Comment: works perfectly....for some reason it wasnt working at the top of the page!

Comment: @user2405912 - it was probably running before the page was ready. As long as you keep it right before the `</body<>` tag it will work as expected. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
var qty1 = document.getElementById("qty[1]");
var qty2 = document.getElementById("qty[2]");
var total_qty = document.getElementById("total_qty");
qty1.onchange = function() {
  var total = parseInt(qty1.value) + parseInt(qty2.value);
  total_qty.value = total;
}
qty2.onchange = function() {
  var total = parseInt(qty1.value) + parseInt(qty2.value);
  total_qty.value = total;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SGY5E/